# How to convert this into a down counter?

Tags: flipflop, counter, ripple-counter

I have been learning counters and am able to design an asynchronous UP counter with JK flip flops in Multisim, however I am unable to convert it to an asynchronous DOWN counter.

My UP counter counts properly 0-1-2-3-0-1-2-3, however my DOWN counter counts 0-2-1-3-0-2-1-3.
I want it to count 3-2-1-0-3-2-1-0.
How should I fix my DOWN counter?

My UP counter
[image]

My DOWN counter
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it, it counts 0-3-2-1-0-3-2-1-0

[image]

Answer (score -1):

- 2 10 to 11
- 1 01 to 10
- 3 11 to 01
- 0 00 to 00
- What is the difference ?  swapped clock input position caused a problem.

  - swap out bits and invert LSB
- note you can XOR output to count down